# JSONP not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

http://jsfiddle.net/baEXg/
I have no clue why it isn't working, the "button" works, anything below $.getJSON doesnt

Comment: I think [it got scared now](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/rfAFU/), because it's working like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, what does callback=? exactly mean?

Comment: @Shef: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: When you include an additional "?" in an AJAX call, JQuery interprets that as meaning it's a JSONP call, and creates a call back function that calls whatever callback or success() function you have defined. It then replaces the ? with the name of this function, and as long as the server you are calling returns something like "NAME_OF_CALLBACK(DATA)", jquery will then call that function, which should call your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) request to be treated as `JSONP` you must specify a `callback=?` in the URL.

It's even in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), consult them, they don't bite:

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

Here is a [forked demo of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/rfAFU/).

Comment: Thanks, wierd, i have an example that works/worked without callback=?, im getting crazy.

Comment: @Writecoder: It might have worked because your request might have been JSON and your server side layer outputted back a JSON object. JSON is different than JSONP, I hope you know the difference already. So, without seeing what you had client and server side, which was working, I can't tell why it was doing so.